Azure Function SQL-triggered scaling issue: High target worker count but single worker execution
I have a problem with scaling up an Azure Function that is SQL-triggered. Here are the details:
I have a table with around 4 million records, and my host configuration for the trigger is:
jsonCopy"sql": {
  "maxBatchSize": 100,
  "pollingIntervalMs": 200,
  "maxChangesPerWorker": 50000,
  "commandTimeout": "00:05:00"
}

I've tried changing these to really small values, but then I get a message like this:
2024-09-01T13:26:42Z [Verbose] Target worker count for '16ace858c406cf50' is '38714'    
2024-09-01T13:26:42Z [Verbose] No enabled functions or scale votes so scaling in

Even when the Target worker count was huge, the function execution count indicated that it works on a single worker. I don't see any action from the scale-up controller that would indicate an increase in the number of workers.
Why isn't my Azure Function scaling up despite the high target worker count?
What does the "No enabled functions or scale votes so scaling in" message mean in this context?
How can I configure my Azure Function to properly scale and utilize multiple workers for processing my large SQL table?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Which plan are you using for your function?

In Azure Function Automatic scaling is only available in Consumption, Premium  and Flex consumption plan.
When using Dedicated App Service plan auto scale is need to configured based on the requirement.
As mentioned in this MS Document.
In App service plan autoscaling varies based on which SKU is used.
Auto scale is disabled by default in Azure function for App service plan.
It Needs to configure rule based configuration.



Note : Make sure to use Consumption or Premium plan for function as it has Autoscaling based on traffic.

